# Flask Server Side Session creates new session instead of maintaining

Tags: flask, session, next.js, flask-restful

I am using next.js to call functions from a flask restful backend. I have two backend functions, a login class and a inbox class. I converted from client side sessions to server side sessions so I could render data before page load. My login route creates a session and stores a key value pair that is formatted like this: 'logged_in_user':'username_inputted_by_user'. I store this here because I need to access the username for the inbox function. When I run the Login class, the session is successfully created and the value 'logged_in_user' is stored in the session. However, when the page redirects and hits the Inbox class, it creates another session for some reason. So when the Inbox function tries to access the variable 'logged_in_user' and use it, it gets a value of none, because the current session doesn't contain this info, the previous session does. I have read lots about cors and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials being the problem, but I have tried all these solutions and nothing works. Anyone have any ideas? My functions are below.

Flask Login class:

```html
class Inbox(Resource):
    parser = SessionEnabledRequestParser()
    def get(self):
        self.parser.maintain_session()

        logged_in_username=session.get("logged_in_username")
        print(logged_in_username)

        try:
            viewed_message_logs = Messages.query.filter(Messages.username==logged_in_username).filter(Messages.viewed=='Viewed').all() 
            unviewed_message_logs = Messages.query.filter(Messages.username==logged_in_username).filter(Messages.viewed=='Unviewed').all()

            viewed_formatted_messages = [
                {
                    "game": message.game,
                    "body": message.message,
                    "date": message.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                } for message in viewed_message_logs
            ]

            unviewed_formatted_messages = [
                {
                    "game": message.game,
                    "body": message.message,
                    "date": message.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                } for message in unviewed_message_logs
            ]


            return {'status':200, 'viewedMessages': viewed_formatted_messages, 'unviewedMessages': unviewed_formatted_messages}

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            return { 'status': 400, 'redirect':'/api/test/account', 'message':'There was an error processing the page. Please try your action again or submit a feedback ticket.'}

api.add_resource(Inbox, '/api/test/inbox')
```

My code that attempted to maintain the session:

```html
class SessionEnabledRequestParser(reqparse.RequestParser):
    def maintain_session(self):
        session.permanent = True
```

And my next.js frontend attempting to call the inbox class:

```html
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test/inbox', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })

        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
        }

        const data = await res.json()

        return {
            props: { data }
        }

    } catch (e) {

        console.log(e)

        // return {
        //     redirect: {
        //         destination: '/login',
        //         permanent: false
        //     }
        // }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            cookieReq
        }
    }
}
```

Please comment if you need any more info from me. I desperately need to solve this problem. Thank you